# C: Problem with pointers and multiple structs

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors

I have a simple implementation of linked lists as structures. But when I define a set of linked lists (again as a structure) I am having trouble accessing the first nodes of the respective linked lists: While for example

```
list->first_node = NULL;
```

works as expected

```
set_of_lists->list_1->first_node = NULL;
```

does not. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong? (Below you can find a minimum working example.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node_
{
    int data;
    struct node_ *next_node;
};

struct linked_list_
{
    struct node_ *first_node;
};

struct set_of_linked_lists_
{
    struct linked_list_ *list_1;
    struct linked_list_ *list_2;
    struct linked_list_ *list_3;
};

int main()
{
    struct set_of_linked_lists_ *set_of_lists = malloc(sizeof(struct set_of_linked_lists_));
    struct linked_list_ *list = malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list_));

    list->first_node = NULL;  // this works

    set_of_lists->list_1->first_node = NULL;  // this does not

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Style guide: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly
because they are [postfix operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3).
They should not be written with spaces around them.
Writing `list -> first_node` is not idiomatic C and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use `list->first_node`.

Comment: Your "this does not" line fails because you've not initialized the pointer members `list_1`, `list_2` and `list_3` of the allocated `set_of_lists` to point to any list.  You'd need something like `set_of_lists->list_1 = extra_list;` before you could do `set_of_lists->list_1->first_node = NULL;`.  Consider whether you want pointers in `struct set_of_linked_lists_`; you might be better off with three simple non-pointer members like `struct linked_list_ list_1;`.  OTOH, that would mean you use `set_of_lists->list_1.first_node = NULL;` which interleaves dots and arrows, which is less consistent.

Comment: I wonder what compilation error do you get with this code? If it compiles fine without warning or error, there is no reason to add the `compilation-errors` tag. Compilation errors are very different from runtime errors. They have different reasons and different effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you've assigned memory to the object that `set_of_lists` points to, you unfortunately have yet not assigned any value to `set_of_lists -> list_1`. Thus, it's value is arbitrary and, in particular, is not a valid `linked_list_*`. This means your attempt to assign `NULL` to `set_of_lists -> list_1 -> first_node`, since it's trying to access the `first_node` member of an invalid object pointer of `set_of_lists -> list_1`, will very likely lead to something like a segmentation fault.

As [Jonathan Leffler's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77740677/c-problem-with-pointers-and-multiple-structs/77740685#comment137053531_77740677) indicates, to make this work properly, you would need to first assign a valid object to the `list_1` member, such as a new `extra_list` object pointer, or perhaps use your `list` object with something like `set_of_lists->list_1 = list;`. Also, you will need to do likewise for the `list_2` and `list_3` members before possibly using them.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct node_
{
    int           data;
    struct node_* next_node;
};

struct linked_list_
{
    struct node_* first_node;
};

struct set_of_linked_lists_
{
    struct linked_list_* list_1;
    struct linked_list_* list_2;
    struct linked_list_* list_3;
};
```

This is your data. Then, in `main`, `set_of_lists_` is declared as a pointers to this `set_of_linked_lists_`

```
    struct set_of_linked_lists_* set_of_lists =
        malloc(sizeof(struct set_of_linked_lists_));
```

When you write

```
    set_of_lists->list_1->first_node =
        NULL;  // this does not
```

it fails because in `set_of_lists_` the 3 pointers points to nothing. As you wrote

```
    struct set_of_linked_lists_* set_of_lists =
        malloc(sizeof(struct set_of_linked_lists_));
    struct linked_list_* list =
        malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list_));

    list->first_node = NULL;  // this works

    set_of_lists->list_1->first_node =
        NULL;  // this does not
```

You could use `list` and write

```
    list->first_node = NULL;  // this works
    set_of_lists->list_1 = list;  // this also works
    set_of_lists->list_2 = list;  // this also works
    set_of_lists->list_3 = list;  // this also works
    set_of_lists->list_3->first_node = NULL;
```

And it works since all 3 pointers points to `list` and `list` is
 `struct linked_list_*`

#### about the code

- Note that, as the names suggest --- `list_1`, `list_2` and `list_3` --- the set could be an array of lists, easier to use and to reason about, as in

```
    struct linked_list_ my_list[3];
    my_list[0].first_node = NULL;
    // or even
    struct linked_list_* p_list[3] = {NULL, NULL, NULL};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i += 1)
    {
        p_list[i] =
            malloc(sizeof(struct set_of_linked_lists_));
        p_list[i]->first_node = NULL;
    }
```

- Consider that the set could be just a linked list of lists, using the same code for `List`, just by changing the notion of `Node`.
- It is convenient to save `size` as a metadata of each list, and use just pointers in all functions.
- if you can choose, double linked lists are far more simpler to program than single linked ones: it is a mess to navigate the list having pointers to just one side.

### a simple example

Follows here an example using a `Set` as a *container*  of `List` as a container of `Node` that may be easier to read and to build upon. It uses some form of encapsulation and OOP principles.

#### a `Node`

```
// Node
typedef struct node_
{
    int           data;
    struct node_* next;
} Node;  // a node

int so_print_n(Node*, const char* msg);
```

`so_print_n()` just prints a node. `msg` is an optional message.

#### a `List` as a collection of `Node`

```
// List
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    Node*  tail;
    Node*  head;
} List;  // a (possibly empty) list of nodes

List* so_create_l();
List* so_delete_l(List*);
int   so_insert_back(const int data, List*);
int   so_insert_front(const int data, List*);
int   so_insert_multi_back(List*, const unsigned N, ...);
int   so_insert_multi_front(List*, const unsigned N, ...);
int   so_insert_pos(const int data, const size_t N, List*);
int   so_print_l(List*, const char* msg);
```

- Here a list has metadata, `head` `tail` and `size` with the obvious contents.
- there are functions to manipulate `Lists` as a unit. `so_insert` has options for inserting at the front, back and nth position in the list.
- `si_insert_multi_` has options to insert multiple items at once, at the fron and at the back.
- `so_print_l` prints a lists using `so_print` for a `Node`

#### a `Set` as a container of `List`

```
// Set
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    size_t limit;
    List** L;
} Set;  // a (possibly empty) set of lists

Set* so_create_s(size_t size);
Set* so_delete_s(Set*);
int  so_insert_s(List*, Set*);
```

Here `Set` is just an array of pointers to `List`, so it can be used as an array instead of `list_1`, `list_2` and `list_3` in the original code.
Since this is just an example we have just the minimum for testing:

- create
- delete
- insert

And the functions uses just pointers. You may find this way of writing easier to read and change.

#### `main` for a test

```
int main(void)
{
  List* x3 = so_create_l();
  so_insert_multi_back(x3, 6, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18);
  List* x5 = so_create_l();
  so_insert_multi_back(x5, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20);
  List* x7 = so_create_l();
  so_insert_multi_back(x7, 6, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42);

  Set* S = so_create_s(20);
  so_insert_s(x3, S);
  so_insert_s(x5, S);
  so_insert_s(x7, S);
  so_insert_s(x7, S); // try to insert x7 again
  printf(
      "\t%llu/%llu lists in set\n\n", S->size, S->limit);
  so_print_l(x7, "[Last list] ");
  so_print_l(S->L[S->size-1], "[Last list, from set] ");
  so_print_l(x5, "[x5] ");
  so_print_l(x3, "[x3] ");
  S = so_delete_s(S);
  return 0;
}
```

This program:

- builds 3 lists
- inserts them in a set
- uses the set to print them
- frees everything

Creating a `List` this way may be as simple as writing

```
  List* x7 = so_create_l();
  so_insert_multi_back(x7, 6, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42);
```

Insert the `x7` list as above in a set is a matter of calling

```
   Set* S = so_create_s(20);
   so_insert_s(x7, S);
```

Printing a list is another call

```
    so_print_l(x7, "[Last list] ");
    so_print_l(S->L[S->size-1], "[Last list, from set] ");
```

Here the list is printed from a `Set` using the index, and using its address. And we can see the convenience of having the optional `msg` argument:

#### example output

```
[Last list]     #6 elements in list.
    head element: 7
    tail element: 42
7 14 21 28 35 42
[-----]

[Last list, from set]     #6 elements in list.
    head element: 7
    tail element: 42
7 14 21 28 35 42
[-----]
```

#### complete outut from this `main`

```
creating set for 20 lists
        3/20 lists in set

[Last list]     #6 elements in list.
    head element: 7
    tail element: 42
7 14 21 28 35 42
[-----]

[Last list, from set]     #6 elements in list.
    head element: 7
    tail element: 42
7 14 21 28 35 42
[-----]

[x5]     #4 elements in list.
    head element: 5
    tail element: 20
5 10 15 20
[-----]

[x3]     #6 elements in list.
    head element: 3
    tail element: 18
3 6 9 12 15 18
[-----]


destroying set (3/20 lists)
```

#### Complete code for the example

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Node
typedef struct node_
{
    int           data;
    struct node_* next;
} Node;  // a node

int so_print_n(Node*, const char* msg);

// List
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    Node*  tail;
    Node*  head;
} List;  // a (possibly empty) list of nodes

List* so_create_l();
List* so_delete_l(List*);
int   so_insert_back(const int data, List*);
int   so_insert_front(const int data, List*);
int   so_insert_multi_back(List*, const unsigned N, ...);
int   so_insert_multi_front(List*, const unsigned N, ...);
int   so_insert_pos(const int data, const size_t N, List*);
int   so_print_l(List*, const char* msg);

// Set
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    size_t limit;
    List** L;
} Set;  // a (possibly empty) set of lists

Set* so_create_s(size_t size);
Set* so_delete_s(Set*);
int  so_insert_s(List*, Set*);

int main(void)
{
    List* x3 = so_create_l();
    so_insert_multi_back(x3, 6, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18);
    List* x5 = so_create_l();
    so_insert_multi_back(x5, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20);
    List* x7 = so_create_l();
    so_insert_multi_back(x7, 6, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42);

    Set* S = so_create_s(20);
    so_insert_s(x3, S);
    so_insert_s(x5, S);
    so_insert_s(x7, S);
    printf(
        "\t%llu/%llu lists in set\n\n", S->size, S->limit);
    so_print_l(x7, "[Last list] ");
    so_print_l(S->L[S->size-1], "[Last list, from set] ");
    so_print_l(x5, "[x5] ");
    so_print_l(x3, "[x3] ");
    S = so_delete_s(S);
    return 0;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////// Code for Nodes


// print a single 'node' 'msg' is an optional prefix
int so_print_n(Node* node, const char* msg)
{
    if (node == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("%d ", node->data);
    return 0;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////// Code for Lists

// returns a pointer to an empty list
List* so_create_l()
{
    List* list = malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (list == NULL) return NULL;
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    list->size = 0;
    return list;
}

// deletes 'del' and returns 'NULL' to invalidate pointer
List* so_delete_l(List* del)
{
    if (del == NULL) return NULL;  // no list
    for (size_t i = 0; i < del->size; i += 1)
    {  // delete nodes, 1 by 1
        Node* save = del->head->next;
        free(del->head);
        del->head = save;
    };
    free(del);  // delete list
    return NULL;
}

// inserts 'info' at the tail of the list
int so_insert_back(const int info, List* list)
{
    if (list == NULL) return -1;  // no list
    Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (node == NULL) return -2;  // no alloc
    node->data = info;
    if (list->size == 0)  // first node
    {
        node->next = NULL;
        list->size = 1;
        list->head = node;
        list->tail = node;
        return 0;  // 1st node
    };
    node->next       = NULL;
    list->tail->next = node;
    list->tail       = node;
    list->size += 1;
    return 0;
}

// inserts 'info' at the head of the list
int so_insert_front(const int info, List* list)
{
    if (list == NULL) return -1;  // no list
    Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (node == NULL) return -2;  // no alloc
    node->data = info;
    if (list->size == 0)
    {
        node->next = NULL;
        list->size = 1;
        list->head = node;
        list->tail = node;
        return 0;  // 1st node
    };
    node->next = list->head;
    list->head = node;
    list->size += 1;
    return 0;
}

// inserts  all nodes at the tail
int so_insert_multi_back(List* list, const unsigned N, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
        so_insert_back(va_arg(args, int), list);
    va_end(args);
    return 0;
}

// inserts  all nodes at the head
int so_insert_multi_front(List* list, const unsigned N, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
        so_insert_front(va_arg(args, int), list);
    va_end(args);
    return 0;
}

// inserts  'el' at position 'pos' in the list
int so_insert_pos(
    const int el, const size_t pos, List* list)
{
    if (pos == 0) return so_insert_back(el, list);
    if (list->size == 0) return so_insert_front(el, list);
    if (list->size >= pos) return so_insert_back(el, list);
    // list is not empty
    // create the new node
    Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (node == NULL) return -1;
    node->data = el;  // data loaded
    // navigate to position
    Node* p = list->head;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < pos - 1; i += 1) p = p->next;
    // insert 'node' after p
    node->next = p->next;
    p->next    = node;
    list->size += 1;
    return 0;  // 1st node
}

// prints a list on screen
int so_print_l(List* list, const char* msg)
{
    if (list == NULL)
    {
        printf("No valid list!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (list->size == 0)
    {
        printf("list is empty\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf(
        "\
    #%llu elements in list.\n\
    head element: %i\n\
    tail element: %i\n",
        list->size, list->head->data, list->tail->data);
    Node* p = list->head;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < list->size; i += 1)
    {
        so_print_n(p, NULL);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\n[-----]\n\n");
    return 0;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////// Code for Sets

// returns a pointer to a new set of lists
Set* so_create_s(size_t size)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "creating set for %llu lists\n", size);
    Set* set = malloc(sizeof(Set));
    if (set == NULL) return NULL;
    set->limit = size;
    set->size  = 0;
    set->L     = (List**)malloc(size*sizeof(List*));
    if (set->L == NULL)
    {
        free(set);
        return NULL;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < set->size; i += 1)
    {
        set->L[i] = malloc(sizeof(List*));  // should check
        set->L[i] = NULL;
    }
    return set;
}

// deletes a 'set'
Set* so_delete_s(Set* set)
{
    if (set == NULL) return NULL;
    fprintf(
        stderr, "\ndestroying set (%llu/%llu lists)\n",
        set->size, set->limit);
    if (set->size == 0) return NULL;
    // delete all lists in set
    size_t n = set->size;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i += 1)
        if (set->L[i] != NULL)
            set->L[i] = so_delete_l(set->L[i]);
    free(set->L); // pointers
    free(set);
    return NULL;
}

// inserts 'list' into 'set'
int so_insert_s(List* list, Set* set)
{
    if (list == NULL) return -1;
    if (set == NULL) return -2;
    // full?
    if (set->size == set->limit) return -3;
    // check for list already in the set
    for (size_t i = 0; i < set->size; i += 1)
        if (set->L[i] == list) return -4;
    set->L[set->size] = list;
    set->size += 1;  // count this one
    return 0;
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77740677/c-problem-with-pointers-and-multiple-structs
```

Note that `Set` could be just another `List`, by changing `Node` to something like

```
// Node
typedef struct node_
{
    void*         data; // point to some data
    struct node_* next;
} Node;  // a node
```

And writing functions for `Node` manipulation using the powers of `void*` in `C`.

In *`java`* or *`C++`* or *`Python`*  lists are used this way, as just containers of some data.